# Rails - Display inline rails errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

How can I condense my code into a single statement:

```
<% @policyholderdetail.errors.each do |attr,msg| %>
  <% if attr == :title %>
    <li><%=attr %> <%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I would like to show only the errors for `:title` next to the field but feel there should be a better statement to do this as opposed to looping through all of the errors until I get to the one I want.

Question - can I condense the first two lines into one better statement?

Answer (score 2):

You can write:  `@policyholderdetail.errors[:title]`. See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#working-with-validation-errors).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
  <% if @policyholderdetail.errors[:title].present? %>
```